# centering the contents of an column in GWT Bootstrap cell table

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt-bootstrap

I have an cell table and the column data are the check boxes i want align these check boxes to center of that column

i tried with`column.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);` 
and using text-align:middle in css. but it doesn't seem to work .Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
    Column<Person, Boolean> checkColumn = new Column<Person, Boolean>(
        new CheckboxCell(true, false)) {
      @Override
      public Boolean getValue(Person object) {
        // check box function
      }
    };
    checkColumn.setHorizontalAlignment(HasAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Works fine for me.

Since you didn't provide much code I can only make several assumptions:

- Check that your cell table CSS [if your using custom ones] isn't over writing the alignment
- Double check your aligning the right column [happens]
- If you are using UiBinder, check to make sure you only set alignment in either your java class or the xml